# Генераторы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Очень сильно пытаюсь но ни как не могу понять как работают такие выражения в Python 3.

```
new_list = [item for sublist in main_list for item in sublist]
```

Или вот это что значит?

```
sum(1 for line in open('file', 'r'))
```

Ну то есть я видел, что первое выражение распаковывает список списков, а второе подсчитывает количество строк в файле. Но я хочу понять как делать такие вещи ровно в одну строку кода. По тому как у меня получаются решения не самые короткие.

Может кто нибудь подсказать? Или посоветовать почитать что-то где эти вопросы разбираются подробно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это

```
new_list = [item for sublist in main_list for item in sublist]
```

Тоже самое что:

```
new_list = []
for sublist in main_list:
    for item in sublist:
        new_list.append(item)
```

---

А когда вы помещаете файловый объект в цикл, то тот начинает итерировать его. И файловый объект возвращает строки из файла.

Тут вы перебираете строки из файла, но на каждую строку возвращаете `1` и в итоге в `sum` попадает генератор, состоящий из `1` размером в количество строк в файле.

Так что, это:

```
sum(1 for line in open('file', 'r'))
```

можно представить как:

```
num = 0
for line in open('file', 'r'):
    num += 1
```

---

**PS.**

> Может кто нибудь подсказать? Или посоветовать почитать что-то где эти
> вопросы разбираются подробно.

Про подобные фишки можно целые статьи найти, например на хабре:

- https://habr.com/post/421993/
- https://habr.com/post/336160/

Comment: А можно ли таким же образом подсчитать количество слов, букв, и байтов в файле? Я делал это простыми циклами, а таким образом нет.

Comment: @AkimovVadim, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: @AkimovVadim, можно. Но лучше весь файл скачать (`with open('file') as f:` `text = f.read()` `print(text)`), чем построчно (не думаю, что ваш файл не влезет в память), а там уже можно считать буквы, разделять на слова и т.п. Если возникнут с этим вопросы/проблемы создавайте вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [ i for i in main_list ]
```

Представь, что внутри квадратных скобок (списке) содержится некий echo-код, который на лету генерирует содержимое как только обратятся к этому списку-генератору. Выражение является обычным for-циклом, таким как, например:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

только в квадратных скобках, "print'тятся" готовые элементы перед объявлением цикла, переменная **i** выносится в начало. Вот и вся разница. Можно с переменной **i** вытворять дополнительные операции, например элемент обработать в другой функции, а результат "вставится" в список:

```
new_list = [ some_func(i) for i in range(1,10) ]
```

Второе выражение:

```
sum(1 for line in open('file', 'r'))
```

Это тоже самое, только в функцию передается не список, а объект типа generator

```
def test(a):
    print(type(a))
    print(a)
    # print(list(a)) # Приводим объект generator к list'у
    print(tuple(a)) # Приводим объект generator к tuple'у

test(i for i in range(1,10)) # В функцию передается анонимный объект-generator
```

Ключевые слова для поиска информации по теме: python list comprehension